# How do keep remote MySQL DBs synced up with a master MySQL DB (using PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, database-schema, remote-server

I have a system in which there are several copies of a MySQL DB schema running on remote servers (and it's not possible to consolidate them all into one DB schema in the cloud).

However, this has proven troublesome because whenever the master DB schema is updated, I have to then remotely log into all the other servers and manually update the schemas using the sync tool in MySQL Workbench, which honestly doesn't work very well (i.e., it doesn't catch changes to views, etc.).

As such, I would like to come up with a way to have the master DB schema stored somewhere in AWS and have all the other, remote instances do something like a daily check for anything that's different between the schema locally installed on that server and the master schema in AWS.

Are there tools out there for this sort of thing, and what are they called? Also, because the application itself is written in PHP, using a tool that's easy to use in PHP would be ideal.
Thank you.

Also, I should note that a lot of the remote schemas are stored on servers behind very secure firewalls, so I don't think that pushing the master DB schema to the remote instances will work. Instead, I think that the request for the schema update has to originate from each of the remote servers to the master schema on AWS, if that makes a difference at all.

Comment: This is a pretty significant thing to try to maintain yourself. Is there a reason why you aren't using replication for the schema changes? https://serverfault.com/questions/181871/adding-tables-on-the-master-mysql-database-replication https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-implementation.html

Comment: Paul Degnan, thanks for the reply. I've never heard of MySQL Replication. Is this a standard thing built into MySQL that can be easily set up to have any change made to a master propagated to any number of slaves? Thanks.

Comment: Yup; just built in MySQL functionality

Answer (score 0):

Db-sync project for MySql sounds like the tool for you. Here is git repo: https://github.com/mrjgreen/db-sync

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you.